# Django: append manual queryset to queryset object

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm using **Django 1.5**.

I have a table **MultiUser**

```
class MultiUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_user')
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='shared_user')
    access_level = models.CharField(
        default='Viewer',  
        max_length='100', 
        blank=True
    )
```

This table maps users with access level under owner user. `user` field defines the owner user and `shared_user` is the mapped user who can be either **manager** or **viewer**

I have defined a model manager method to get list of all users including the owner user.

```
def getSharedUsers(self, user):
    # Get owner
    owner = None
    if self.filter(user=user).exists():
        owner = user
    elif self.filter(shared_user=user).exists():
        owner = self.filter(shared_user=user)[0]

    # Get all users
    shared_users = []
    if owner:
        shared_users = self.filter(user=owner)

    shared_users.append({
        'shared_user': owner,
        'access_level': 'OWNER',
        'created': owner.created
    })

    return shared_users
```

Since owner user has no `access_level` defined in the **MultiUser** model. I want to manually append the owner user to the queryset list with `shared_user` field set to the owner user and `access_level` as **owner**.

But this gives error as

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'
```

**It is possible to append manually generated object to the queryset object? If yes how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here when you are using `shared_users = self.filter(user=owner)`, the `shared_users` become a queryset. Well, if you want to append owner to the queryset, you can do it like this:

```
from itertools import chain

shared_users = list(chain(shared_users, [{
    'shared_user': owner,
    'access_level': 'OWNER',
    'created': owner.created
}])
```

But down side is, you will lose support functionality of a queryset. So you need to use it like a list.

Comment: Can I use it in **Django REST Framework** serializer?

Comment: Is there someway to fake queryset to convert dictionary object in queryset?

Answer (score -1):

You see where is the point of this.

```
# Get all users
shared_users = []
if owner:
    shared_users1 = self.filter(user=owner)

shared_users.append({
    'shared_user': owner,
    'access_level': 'OWNER',
    'created': owner.created
})

return shared_users
```

Comment: why `shared_users1`?